# Custom buttons not working when inside module

Tags: module, joomla-3.3.x, form

So when I put these buttons inside an article they worked fine.

As soon as I put them in a module (so I could show them dependent on if the user is logged in or not) they stopped working.

The first button takes you to the registration page
The second button takes you to log in page
*both via menu items

But now when in a module the first button takes you to log in page and the second stays blank on index.php

My code is as follows below:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<form action="http://get2gethersports.com/edit-user-profile?view=registration" method="get">
    <button type="submit"> Join Now </button>
</form>
<form action="http://get2gethersports.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=login" method="get">
    <button type="submit"> Login </button>
</form>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a form for this? Wouldn't it be easier to use a regular link (and style it as a button using CSS)? For example: `<a href="http://get2gethersports.com/edit-user-profile?view=registration" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>`

Comment: That worked! And I guess I took making a button more literally then I should have...

Comment: Great. That still doesn't answer why your code works in an article but not within a module. I don't see any immediate reason for that. Maybe someone else has an explanation?

Comment: Toggling prepared content might help....

Comment: I did make to prepare content was on. very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular link instead of a form, and style them using CSS, something like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <p>
      <a href="http://example.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=registration" class="btn btn-primary"> Join Now </a>
   </p>
   <p>
      <a href="http://example.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=login" class="btn btn-success"> Login </a>
   </p>
</div>
```